# Knockout.js - passing parameters

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

There is a problem with passing parameter, when I press button, nothing is going and there are no errors in console

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: hotels">
<tr>
   <td data-bind="text: Id"></td>
   <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
   <td data-bind="text: Address"></td>                      
   <td>
       <button data-bind="click: $root.eksportuj" > @Html.Text("Eksportuj") </button>
   </td>
</tr>
```

and

```js
self.eksportuj = function (obj, event) {
    $.ajax({
        ulr: "@Url.Action("eksport", "Controller")",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'Id' : obj.Id},
        success: function (result)
           {
               alert("True");
           },
        error: function()
           {
               alert("Error");
           }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is `obj.Id` an observable?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is in non-enclosed `button` tag, or `tbody` tag

`<button data-bind="click: $root.eksportuj" > @Html.Text("Eksportuj") </button>`

Simle [**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mojqm3hf/) works as expected

**JSFiddle DEMO code:**

```
var viewModel = new function()
{
    var self = this;
    self.hotels = ko.observableArray([{
        Id : "1",
        Name : "N1",
        Address : "A1"
    },{
        Id : "2",
        Name : "N2",
        Address : "A2"
    }]);

    self.eksportuj = function (obj, event) {
       alert(obj.Id)
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel)
```

Comment: @user3671757 change `alert` to `console.log`